# Enqueue Wordpress Plugin Admin Stylesheet In Another Directory(Up One)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to enqueue a stylesheet for my admin plugins page.The file I am working in has this current path,

```
\plugins\my-plugin-name\includes\fileiamworkingon.php
```

All I  am looking to do is enqueue a stylesheet that sits one directory up from the directory I am currently in. The path to this stylesheet is like so,

```
\plugins\my-plugin-name\css\styles.css
```

I currently have it working by calling an add action hook inside of my classes constructor function like this:

`add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'pluginStyles'));`

As you can see, it then calls a pluginStyles function where I perform the following code,

```
public function pluginStyles() {
    wp_register_style('my_plugin_stylesheet',  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../css/styles.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('my_plugin_stylesheet');
}
```

Currently this is the only way I can get it to work because of adding that little subtle '../' to the file path. Otherwise, it tries to access the css folder from inside the 'includes' directory, which obviously no css folder exists in there.

This doesn't seem like the best solution, and maybe there is a more "Wordpress Way" of solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I've done in the past - define a constant in the main `\plugins\my-plugin-name\my-plugin-name.php` file:

```
/** Define plugin path constant */
if (!defined('PLUGIN_PATH')) {
    define('PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
}
```

And enqueue in your `\includes\fileiamworkingon.php` file:

```
/** Enqueue from any other file in the plugin directory */
wp_register_style('my_plugin_stylesheet',  PLUGIN_PATH . 'css/styles.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('my_plugin_stylesheet');
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am still looking through things right now.

Comment: This did not work for me, but I could be utilizing it incorrectly. I totally rephrased my question as well with new details, as I felt it was lacking.

Comment: Seems I made a small mistake in the code. I just edited to have`plugin_dir_url` instead of `plugin_dir_path`.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to accept this as the answer for my use case, as having a global variable for that path may come in handy when I start writing more code. I will see if Johannes has anything to add or has any objections, seeing as in I changed my question quite a bit on him.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the plugin directory path using `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );`

So you should be able to register your stylesheet this way:

```
function my_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'my_plugin_stylesheet',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'my-plugin-name/css/styles.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_plugin_stylesheet' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am still looking through things right now.

Comment: I used your solution to get mostly all the way there, but if you see, I rephrased my question quite a bit, as I felt it was very bland(and did not really explain what I was doing well). I have it working now, but if you see my question edits, it only works if I add a '../' to the path

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in 'fileiamworkingon.php':

```
 wp_enqueue_style('styles', plugin_dir_path() . '../css/styles.css', array(), null);
```

The '../' will move you back a directory.

Comment: This is probably not the way to go, did you get this from WP docs?

Comment: Also, just wanted to let you know, that copying and pasting that ended up in my code attempting to load the styles.css file from the path "sitename.com/css/styles.css".